# Spotfire, Plot Currency Values in Y Axis

Tags: types, currency, spotfire

I am creating a waterfall chart in spotfire and I have project names in the X Axis.

I wanted to show the project cost in the Y axis. In the table there are two columns one is Currency Type (Which shows Currency symbols like $, USD MM, Rs etc) and Another column as project cost.

In the Y axis I wanted to show the cost along with the currency type for eg ; $500 or Rs. 10000 etc. I concatenated the field currency type and Project cost but the data type is string so I am not able to show the exact currency in Y axis.

Any Solution for this?

Comment: It sounds as though the currency symbol varies throughout the table. Is that correct? My understanding is that it wouldn't make sense to mix currency types, so I would make a separate chart for each currency type. You could also create a document property that is something like the unique concatenation of the currency symbol field and stick that in a short message in a text box.

Comment: Yes, the currency Symbol Varies. But I need all the types in one chart itsels ie Y axis

Comment: I would add a conversion factor to make all of the values comparable. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have them on the same axis. You can add the original currency type and value in the tooltip display.